# RNS seq analysis, using R, make pheatmap, all looks blue

Tags: r, pheatmap

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlqme.jpg)[enter image description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUCTO.jpg)

I am trying to make heatmap using pheatmap fucntion. My problem is always all the values between high and low are showing as same color. 
Is there any way to show more dynamic heatmap picture?

Comment: You should show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 library(RColorBrewer)
 colors <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Blues"))(255)
 pheatmap(mat,
          col=colors,
          )
```

It should work if your data is correctly formatted.